# Visual Studio 2015 diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise when i started the project the diagnostic 
tool worked fine, But after a few weeks of work it stopped working at the moment it not working(in any project), this is the Diagnostic Hub message:
`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

**fix by restart PC.**